# Partial Matches in a String[]

Tags: c#, linq

I have two string arrays; one is `list` and the other is `find`

I want to be able to count the number of items in find that are partially contained within 'list' using extension methods and linq.  Here is a summary of how I would do it within a few nested loops:

```
int Count = 0;

foreach (string f in find)
{
    foreach (string l in list)
    {
         if (l.Contains(f))
         {
              Count++;
              break;
         }
    }
}

return Count;
```

I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
int Count = list.Select(...);
```

In my actual application, `list` is an element within a linq query of type `IQueryable<string>` and `find` is a static `string[]`.  I'd like to be able to perform the count above within linq.  I know I will probably have to use `.AsEnumerable()`  as whatever the solution is probably wont be able to be translated to SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int count = find.Count(f => list.Any(s => s.Contains(f)));
```

Comment: The first `l` should actually be `list`

Answer (score 1):

```
var count = (
  from f in find
  where list.Any(l => f.Contains(l))
  select f).Count();
```

Comment: Thanks for the expanded syntax